# Passing an Integer through function arg gives string 'length

Tags: javascript, event-listener

So my anomaly is this:  I am passing an integer value 'g' to my 'turn' function inside my `.addEventListener`, for some reason, when the integer comes out on the other side through the `document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=j` line, it displays the sting 'length' when I fully expected the integer I passed in initially,  why is this doing this?

```
  var initials=document.getElementsByClassName("letter")

  function load(){

    for(var g in initials)
    {
      initials[g].addEventListener("click", function(){turn(g)})
      initials[g].innerHTML=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*alpha.length)]
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="thischanged "+g
    }
  }

  function turn(j){
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=j
      }
```

Comment: Array iteration is one problem, see the duplicate to solve it. There's another problem though with treating `g` as if it were a number or string, however it's actually a DOMNode. Not sure what you're expecting from it, but maybe something like `g.innerHTML` or such.

Comment: @deceze I guess my real question is, how do I use this loop to assign a unique event listener to each node, based on the individual node itself

Comment: @mattlao, I know it might not seem like it, but your question really is a duplicate. The problem you're seeing is because you're using `for/in` incorrectly. Read **3. Use for-in correctly** in the accepted answer in [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/152786).

Answer (score 0):

construct `for(var g in initials)` enumerates property names. at least you need to pass in `initials[g]`.